# How to post the value in text box the were generate using looping from database

Tags: php, html

[image]

I have a table that were listed using looping from mysql database. In column edit i had a textbox and edit button. I want to post the value of the text box when user click edit button.My  problem is when i click the edit button the value in the post take the value of last one(which group name = QW).

Comment: if you are posting the complete page (and not every line is a form of its own) you should use name="QW[]" to make it an array

Comment: more info (how does your form look like) is needed

Comment: SHow us your code please. Otherwise all you will get are guesses

Answer (score 0):

> when i click the edit button the value in the post take the value of last one(which group name = QW).

So give them unique names.

Probably ones which incorporate the row number in the database.

e.g.

```
name="foo[row_number]"
```

… which will then let you loop over `$_POST['foo']` as an associative array.